# Trying to return columns in a matrix but method is undefined with correct console output

Tags: javascript, matrix

So, I have put in some time doing this puzzle and I finally have my console output correct.  I am new to using JavaScript methods and I am having the hardest time figuring out why `this.columns` is `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
export var Matrix = function(matrix) {
    var self = this
    let splitMatrix = matrix.split("\n") 
    self.rows = splitMatrix.map(function(row){return row.split(" ").map( Number )})
    self.columns = self.rows[0].forEach(function(index){
        self.rows.map(function(column){
            console.log(column[index])
        })
    });
}
```

The specific test case I am trying to pass is here:

```
  test('can extract column from non-square matrix', () => {
    expect(new Matrix('1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9\n8 7 6').columns[2]).toEqual([3, 6, 9, 6]);
  });
```

The matrix is a string separated by `\n`.  This will give you some insight as to why I have the code the way I do.

Here is my console output.

```
 console.log matrix.js:7
    1

  console.log matrix.js:7
    4

  console.log matrix.js:7
    7

  console.log matrix.js:7
    8

  console.log matrix.js:7
    2

  console.log matrix.js:7
    5

  console.log matrix.js:7
    8

  console.log matrix.js:7
    7

  console.log matrix.js:7
    3

  console.log matrix.js:7
    6

  console.log matrix.js:7
    9

  console.log matrix.js:7
    6
```

All is good and gravy... except the fact that `self.columns === undefined`

It's an obvious scope issue but I am completely missing it.

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything (well…it returns `undefined`). Maybe you want `map()`?

Comment: Even with map, `console.log(self.columns)` returns `undefined` :( EDIT: hmm.. it actually returns `[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `reduce()` to build the array of columns. `map()`ing over the rows doesn't really work since the number of columns may be different than the number of rows.

For each row you will iterate over the numbers and add the number to the appropriate column using the index in the `forEach`.

Something like:

```js
var Matrix = function(matrix) {
    let splitMatrix = matrix.split("\n") 
    this.rows = splitMatrix.map(row =>  row.split(" ").map( Number ))
    this.columns = this.rows.reduce((arr, row) => {
        row.forEach((n, i) => {
            if (!arr[i]) arr[i] = []  // if there's no entry yet for column i, make it
            arr[i].push(n)            // push to the column
        })
        return arr
        
    }, []);
}

console.log(new Matrix('1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9\n8 7 6').columns)
```

You could also make a simple function to get a specific column if you didn't want to calculate them all at once:

```js
var Matrix = function(matrix) {
    let splitMatrix = matrix.split("\n") 
    this.rows = splitMatrix.map(row =>  row.split(" ").map( Number ))
}

Matrix.prototype.getColumn = function (colNum){
  // will return undefined if no value in column
  return this.rows.map(r => r[colNum])
}

let M = new Matrix('1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9\n8 7 6')
console.log(M.getColumn(1))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Mark.  I will make sure to dive into your columns method to understand exactly how it works.  I was really hoping my syntax would have worked out with a small tweak, but it probably wasn't the best route anyway.